# Maven3: replace transitive dependency of a direct dependency in dependency management

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to fix the issue described here:
http://www.jayway.com/2013/04/12/solving-asm-conflicts-after-upgrading-to-groovy-2-1/

I have one dependency (Swagger->Jersey) that uses ASM 3.2 and one RestAssured that requires Groovy that requires ASM 4.0.

The idea is to replace the dependency to groovy to a dependency groovy-all which does not depend on ASM 4.0 (the class packages seems here but have been renamed using jarjar).

Is it possible to tell maven, in dependency management of a parent pom, that whenever a child depends on RestAssured, it will thus load transitively the groovy-all dependency instead of the normal groovy dependency?

Thanks

---

The aim is that all childs only need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which retrieve groovy-all instead of groovy

And not

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. However, you can use dependency `<exclusions/>`. Furthermore, as a top-level dependency, you can define `groovy-all`.

The article you linked to illustrates the following as a solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Groovy because of classpath issue -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <!-- Needs to be the same version that 
         REST Assured depends on -->
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks but I can obviously read myself the article I linked :) It works fine by the way, just wonder if there is a more elegant solution

Comment: I have no doubt you can read it :) Apologies, if it sounded dumb. You can't do what you would like in this case, but simply add exclusions and a top-level dependency which overrides the artifact+version, I'm afraid.